# Scroll bar for line graph VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graph

I created a line graph in Visual Basic to show how many calories the user eats per day. However, my user requires me to include a scroll bar to scroll back and forward along the x-axis to view more days.

Unfortunately, I have never done anything like this before, and after looking through Stack Overflow and Googling, I cannot see any examples of anyone doing so.

Here is a screenshot of my graph so far:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        CalorieChartView = True
        BurntChartView = False
        NetChartView = False
        Dim Series As Series = CalorieChart.Series(0)
        'keeps track of if the chart is empty, starting as true
        Dim empty As Boolean = True
        'Clears the chart
        Series.Points.Clear()
        'Draws the chart in dark red
        Series.Color = Color.DarkRed
        'The legend text is changed
        Series.LegendText = "Calories Consumed"
        'For each of the past 8 days, a point is plotted with how many calories were eaten in that day
        For i = -7 To 0
            Series.Points.Add(User.GetCaloriesEaten(User.Username, Date.Now.AddDays(i)))
            Series.Points(7 + i).AxisLabel = Date.Now.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            'If any of the points are not 0
            If User.GetCaloriesEaten(User.Username, Date.Now.AddDays(i)) <> 0 Then
                'the chart is not empty
                empty = False
            End If
        Next

        HandleEmpty(empty)
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please, check this: [How to scroll MS Chart along x-axis in vb.net](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/695526/How-to-scroll-MS-Chart-along-x-axis-in-vb-net)

Comment: @MaciejLos If you would like the 50 rep, you could write it up as an answer

Comment: I can post that as an answer if it's helpful to you. So, let me know and i'll post ASAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to add a horizontal scroll bar to your graph. I have made some modification and new code to your code as for mock data purpose. Please refer the below code. You can get the idea by running this code separately.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim blockSize As Integer = 10
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
    CalorieChartView = True
    BurntChartView = False
    NetChartView = False

    CalorieChart.Series.Clear()
    Dim series = CalorieChart.Series.Add("My Series")
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32
    'keeps track of if the chart is empty, starting as true
    Dim empty As Boolean = True
    'Clears the chart
    series.Points.Clear()
    'Draws the chart in dark red
    series.Color = Color.DarkRed
    'The legend text is changed
    series.LegendText = "Calories Consumed"
    'For each of the past 8 days, a point is plotted with how many calories were eaten in that day

    Dim sizeOfDayToDisplay As Int16 = 0

    For i = 0 To 100
        'Series.Points.Add(User.GetCaloriesEaten(User.Username, Date.Now.AddDays(i)))
        'Series.Points(7 + i).AxisLabel = Date.Now.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        ''If any of the points are not 0
        'If User.GetCaloriesEaten(User.Username, Date.Now.AddDays(i)) <> 0 Then
        '    'the chart is not empty
        '    empty = False
        'End If

         ' just for testing purpose.
        series.Points.Add(getRandumNumber())
        series.Points(i).AxisLabel = Date.Now.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

        ' series.Points.AddXY(i, Date.Now.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
         sizeOfDayToDisplay += 1
    Next

     'most new code added is below here
    Dim chartArea = CalorieChart.ChartAreas(Series.ChartArea)
    chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0
    chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = sizeOfDayToDisplay
    chartArea.CursorX.AutoScroll = True
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = True
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number
    Dim position As Integer = 0
    Dim size As Integer = blockSize
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(position, size)
    chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = blockSize
    'HandleEmpty(empty)
    'Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
End Sub

Public Function getRandumNumber() As Int16
    Return CInt(Math.Floor((3500 - 1000 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1000
End Function
```

[image: Here is the output graph]

Comment: @mr Popo Did my answer help you? If it did, could you please accept my answer.

Comment: If there is any problem let me know.. I will try to help

Comment: The only problem I have is that I get the scroll bar going farther than the data goes: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9jXk.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCPfR.png)

Comment: You can try with tunning with different settings. You can try changing the block size. In my example above I have set it to 10. You can increase the size of it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this: [How to scroll MS Chart along x-axis in vb.net](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/695526/How-to-scroll-MS-Chart-along-x-axis-in-vb-net), you can use:

```
Chart1.Series("LoadCell").Points.AddY(receivedData)
Chart1.ResetAutoValues()

If Chart1.Series("LoadCell").Points.Count >= 100 Then
     Chart1.Series("LoadCell").Points.RemoveAt(0)
End If
```

> It Auto scales the y axis as well as limiting the x axis to 100 by
>   removing the first entry when the entries exeed 100.

Comment: I am not so sure that this helps by scrolling the graph, but rather auto scales it.

Comment: But it enables user to scroll data in a sort of strange way ;)